# Confusion regarding the relationship between a bootstrap theme and a framework like Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, themes

I am building an Application using Angular2 and want to use Bootstrap as my css framework. I am not a UI expert and hence am looking to buy / use a Bootstrap theme.

Based on my understanding, if I use a bootstrap theme, there should be some .css file that is provided and once included in my html, I will be able to use either the standard bootstrap classes or the custom ones from the theme in order to achieve the look of that theme.

However, when I am looking at various themes, instead of just css, there are usually multiple various .js files and a host of other libraries of other 3rd party components included in that theme.

Also, I am coming across bootstrap themes build on "native" components for Angular 2 (which is my application framework) but I am struggling to understand what or how Angular 2 relates to a bootstrap theme. If Bootstrap 3 is for styling, shouldnt it and hence any Bootstrap theme be agnostic of any framework like Angular 2 / React / whatever?

Any help or resources in clarifying these points would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bootstrap isn't all about styling, it has components (such as DatePicker or Modal) that requires a combination of CSS and JS to work. If you just want the CSS part, simply download their CSS file (or point your link to one of the CDNs) and start stying your code. I believe custom themes need to support Bootstrap components as well, that's why there are JS files there.

Comment: @HarryNinh - that does help clarify my misconception about bootstrap. Thanks. Is there some reference where I can determine exactly what parts of bootstrap are css only and what parts need js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bootstrap uses jQuery and it's clear and obvious that jQuery and
>   Angular are two different frameworks written above JavaScript. So in my personal opinion I think we shouldn't mix up two different frameworks on a single project project (either use jQuery or use Angular).

But in your case as you are doing with Angular so you can use Bootstrap's CSS only for layout and styling and instead of using Bootstrap's default components written on jQuery (like modal, dropdown etc.) there are Bootstrap components available that are re-written using Angular without the dependency of jQuery. You can check [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) and [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap) which have almost all Bootstrap components written completely with Angular.

Alternatively, there is another complete UI framework for Angular based on Google's Material Design specs named [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/). Currently Angular Material for Angular 2 is in beta.

Also there are bundle of official UI [resources](https://angular.io/resources/#!#UI%20Components) that you can use and drive smoothly with Angular.

Comment: Can you provide the reference URL for the quote in your answer for my reference? BTW, I totally agree with it per se. Also, would I be understanding correctly, that by using something like ng-bootstrap, I basically remove the jquery dependency - but I would still be able to use all CSS related goodies in Bootstrap in any case?

Comment: Actually its my personal opinion and opinions of some developers around but there's no such hard rule you can use both as well. I will update you with reference URL shortly once I find some good one. And yes you can use all CSS related goodies of Bootstrap by adding Bootstrap CSS. And for components you can use the above mentioned UI components if you are willing to rely only on Angular without jQuery.

Comment: Just a note: jQuery is a library, not a framework :)